# triple nested mysql selects returns no results when it should

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL Query

```
(SELECT * FROM OperatorRoster as roster 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT *, count(*) as activeSlots FROM Connectors
    group by (operator)) as connectors
ON connectors.operator = roster.operator)
```

Workes fine and return all the values that i need, but i need to use the restult in a new query

but if i try to use it:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM OperatorRoster as roster 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT *, count(*) as activeSlots FROM Connectors
    group by (operator)) as connectors
ON connectors.operator = roster.operator) as q
```

It returs nothing.
how can i query this subquery?

Comment: _"Every derived table must have its own alias."_

Comment: yes, but it still dose not worke i just stripad out the last alias for  readability and it dose not return an error

Comment: If there is _no_ error (how do you check btw?), then if follows the result from the query is zero rows, hence no data.

Comment: you are missing an ON clause of the main join . ` on q.---= Operators.----`

Comment: MySql Workebench dose not return any errors and no rows, but how can the first query give me result when the last dose not? Thy whould be the same?

Comment: Why do you have parenthesis around your group by? Also, when aliasing tables, you don't use `as`. That's used for columns. for aliasing tables, you just `Select * From Employees e`. Mysql might tolerate it fine but it just looks off to me

Comment: @Scotch I guess it looks odd because you are used to Oracle (the only DBMS that does not like `AS` when aliasing tables.) Which is optional but standard and used in all other DBMS (SQL-Server, MySQL, Postgres, DB2, ...) It's optional when aliasing columns as well.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an ON clause of the main join .

```
  on q.___= Operators.___
```

Comment: Yes but that dose no difference and the select should still worke?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an inner join, are you sure that there exist rows where 
`connectors.operator=roster.operator`

if there are no rows that match that requirement then your query shouldn't return any rows

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that since I did a join on operators but select all fields,

```
(SELECT * FROM OperatorRoster as roster 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT *, count(*) as activeSlots FROM Connectors
    group by operator) as connectors
ON connectors.operator = roster.operator)
```

It returns two fields with the same name "connectors.operator" and "roster.operator", and since the last select cant inherit the scoop, it conflicts. 
No clued why it did not return an error but I fixed it by only selecting one operator field.